# Mysteriously changing report format -- Access mailing labels report

Tags: ms-access

Debugging an old Access 2000 database which someone recently added a labels report to. It prints 3 x 10 labels on a standard Avery 5160 layout. Runs flawlessly the first time it's opened, but any time after that goes to a 1 x 9 layout, even if I close and reopen the database. If I copy the original file again to my working directory, I get the same results.  I am not opening the report in design mode.

I have run compact/repair, and even created a new database file and imported all objects, and still get this issue. Is this some strange but known Access bug?... or is the report object itself corrupted? What is the best way to resolve?

Comment: Is Name Autocorrect turned OFF in this database? It should be in all databases, as its nickname, i.e., Name Autocorrupt, is more descriptive of what it does.

Comment: Yes - it is, but I agree re: your name for it it, and assessment. (P.S. Thinking you should have perhaps entered this as an answer rather than a comment..?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a limitation of the installed default printer, I think. Try choosing a specific printer for the labels report.

Comment: Jamo, what Remou said is the only thing I know of that you can test - MS Access has always been finicky with page margins and unexpectedly changing them because of available printer changes. And you're not alone: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35111007/page-margin-surprises-.aspx